# Overriding CSS with a Different Link Color

Tags: html, css

On my page, normal link color is blue and works well.  However, I want to have white links on red background in an alert box.  Can't seem to get this to work.  Tried ordering differently, using `!important`, etc.

```css
.announcestripe {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 964px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  padding: .5em;
}

a:link.announcestripe,
a:visited.announcestripe,
a:hover.announcestripe,
a:active.announcestripe {
  color: #ffffff!important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.announcename {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.announcetext1,
.announcetext2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="announcestripe">
  <span class="announcename">LATEST NEWS:</span>
  <span class="announcetext1"><a href="https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/universal-design-living-laboratory" target="_blank">UDLL Featured in Architectural Digest</a> <img src="../../images/_common/icons/16px/link16white.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="External Link" border="0" /></span>
  <span class="announcetext2"><a href="https://somepage.jwpapp.com/" target="_blank">TEDx Talk About UDLL</a> <img src="../../images/_common/icons/16px/link16white.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="External Link" border="0" /></span>
</div>
```

[image: You can see what it looks like in the attached screenshot.]

Thanks!

Comment: Please take the time to format the code into something readable.

Comment: `announcestripe` belong to parent `div` and not `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your HTML it has to be `.announcestripe a:link`, not `a:link.announcestripe`. The latter would only target `a` elements with the class `announcestripe` (which your HTML doesn't have), whereas the corrected selector targets `a` elements that are **descendants** of an element with the class `announcestripe` (which is the case in your HTML).

```css
.announcestripe {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 964px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  padding: .5em;
}

.announcestripe a:link,
.announcestripe a:visited,
.announcestripe a:hover,
.announcestripe a:active {
  color: #ffffff!important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.announcename {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.announcetext1,
.announcetext2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="announcestripe">
  <span class="announcename">LATEST NEWS:</span>
  <span class="announcetext1"><a href="https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/universal-design-living-laboratory" target="_blank">UDLL Featured in Architectural Digest</a> <img src="../../images/_common/icons/16px/link16white.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="External Link" border="0" /></span>

  <span class="announcetext2"><a href="https://somepage.jwpapp.com/" target="_blank">TEDx Talk About UDLL</a> <img src="../../images/_common/icons/16px/link16white.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="External Link" border="0" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have your link css formatted incorrectly. Instead of putting `a:hover.announcestripe`
insert .`announcestripe` at the start;   `.announcestripe a:hover` Then your desired formatting will work.

```css
.announcestripe {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 964px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  padding: .5em;
}


.anouncestripe a:visited,
.anouncestripe a:hover,
.anouncestripe a:active {
  color: #ffffff!important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.announcename {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.announcetext1,
.announcetext2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="announcestripe">
  <span class="announcename">LATEST NEWS:</span>
  <span class="announcetext1"><a href="https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/universal-design-living-laboratory" target="_blank">UDLL Featured in Architectural Digest</a> <img src="../../images/_common/icons/16px/link16white.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="External Link" border="0" /></span>

  <span class="announcetext2"><a href="https://somepage.jwpapp.com/" target="_blank">TEDx Talk About UDLL</a> <img src="../../images/_common/icons/16px/link16white.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="External Link" border="0" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly does your answer add which my answer hasn't already?

Comment: @connexo I only saw your answer when I posted mine; we were writing at the same time!

Comment: @connexo I suggest you adopt a friendlier tone. I was also only trying to assist the OP

Comment: Sorry, no pun intended. Ofc you only tried to help, but what I said is factually correct nonetheless. Please don't take it as an offense.